# No module named 'geopy' but works in terminal

Tags: python, macos, geopy

I'm trying to run a python program within pyCharm but I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/amywang/Documents/latLong/main.py", line 3, in 
>       from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim ImportError: No module named 'geopy'

However, when I run the same import statement in terminal I don't get an error.

[image]

Any ideas on how I can resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the same python versions? What does `which python` give you on the terminal and what python does pycharm use?

Comment: It sounds like you need to update the preferences of the PyCharm project to point to the correct python interpreter.
Preferences -> Project:SomeProject -> Project Interpreter

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyHughes! That resolved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to update the preferences of the PyCharm project to point to the correct python interpreter.

Preferences -> Project:SomeProject -> Project Interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So here is how I solved it:

1) In the jupyter notebook check on the top right corner to see which environment is activated.

2) In your terminal enter this: " conda env list "
You can see which root you at and also which python environment you use. I use py3 for example.

3) In the terminal enter this: "source activate py3"

4) Now install geopy again: pip install geopy

I hope this helps.